# Coding View in Progress OpenEdge Database

Tags: view, openedge, progress-db

I have started exploring Progress databases and I would like to ask if someone knows how I code a view (Like in SQL) in the OpenEdge Procedure Editor?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It's customary to try something and, when you get stuck, to post the issue you're having.

Comment: I know that Tom, the thing is that i didn't find anything related to that. I only find things like temporary tables, and even a view could be considered like a temp table, they only exists and works per session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no views in Progress. Plenty of other things though, like FOR-statements, joins and other stuff.

In an ABL-editor you can write:

```
FOR EACH table1 NO-LOCK, EACH table2 NO-LOCK WHERE table2.id = table1.id:
  DISPLAY table1.field2 table2.field3 WITH FRAME frOne 20 DOWN.
END.
```

However storing that as a "view" that you can query in the future is not something that is possible.

Don't think about what's possible in SQL or not - you need to focus on Progress instead.

Comment: Thank you so much Jensd. I'll try to explore a little bit more through this way you gave me now.

Answer (score 1):

Rule #1 -- Progress is not SQL.

There is some very limited and very old-style SQL support in the procedure editor.  (It is SQL-89 ish)

It is not something that you should use for anything other than a very quick and extremely simple ad-hoc query.   Such as:

```
select count( * ) from customer.
```

Anything fancier is going to lead to endless pain and frustration.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I read some things before and people say that, we should not consider progress like SQL. I already made a script to extract data from progress table to csv but creating a view i didn't find anything that i could guide for.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CREATE VIEW ne_customer AS
     SELECT cust_no, last_name, street, city, state
     FROM SPORTS.customer
     WHERE state in ('NH', 'MA', 'ME', 'CT', 'RI', 'VT') ;
```

See:

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000035978